# Regex match if word doesn't appear before other word

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this [Regex (Live)](http://rubular.com/r/FnBAn5tYH1):

```
^((?!when|how|where).*?(ARE|WANNA|DO).*\?)$
```

And these three sentences:

```
Hey are we out after the rain?
Where are we meeting?
Dan where are we gonna meet?
```

My regex matches 1 and 3, but should match only 1.

My base rule is that one of the words `when|how|where` can not appear before one of the words `ARE|WANNA|DO`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
^((?!when|how|where).)*?(ARE|WANNA|DO).*\?$
```

Putting the negative lookahead inside a repeating group like `((?!foo).)*` causes the lookahead to be checked before each character is matched, so this would match any number of any character but stop if `foo` were encountered.

Example: http://rubular.com/r/0cw8eaFMXB

Answer (score 1):

Try using this instead:

```
^((?:(?!when|how|where).)*?(ARE|WANNA|DO).*\?)$
  ^^^                   ^
```

This group will 'check' each `.` before matching it and make sure that each dot doesn't have a `when|how|where` ahead.